# How to use wikidata property paths?

Tags: uses-of-open-data, research, wikidata, sparql, rdf

Given a term/concept, I want to decide if it belongs to computer science. For that, I am checking if the concept has a property path to computer science node. In other words, I am checking whether computer science is an ancestral concept.

For this purpose, I am using the following wikidata query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item {
VALUES ?searchTerm { "word2vec"}
SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "EntitySearch".
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org".
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:limit 3 .
    bd:serviceParam mwapi:search ?searchTerm.
    bd:serviceParam mwapi:language "en".
    ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item.
    ?num wikibase:apiOrdinal true.
}
?item (wdt:P279|wdt:P31) ?type
filter exists {?type (wdt:P279|wdt:P361)* wd:Q21198}
}
ORDER BY ?searchTerm ?num
```

However, the query gets timeout.

Therefore, I would like to know if there is another way of solving my approach.

I am only interested in concepts that reaches computer science node using 8 or less hops. For example, is it possible to get all the nodes related to computer science node in 8 or less hops before, and then use this node list as a vocabulary to validate the concepts. Please let me know if my explaination is not clear.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: Our wikidata expert [stanislav-kralin](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/16193/stanislav-kralin) has mentioned that you can also ask for query help at: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Request_a_query

Comment: @philshem Thanks a lot. Sure, I will submit a post in wikidata discussion page :)